# Excel formula into VBA,

Tags: vba

I trying found out the best way to put Excel formula into VBA,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT("2,9)&CONCAT(": ",Q2,"-A"))
```

I have tried this

```
Sub upstreamA()
    i = Right("P2", 9)
    f = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(i, Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(": ", "Q2", "-A").Value, Range("W23").Value)
End Sub
```

but no luck..

Comment: `i = Right("P2", 9)` is problematic because `"P2"` is the string `P2`, not a reference to a `Range`.

Comment: do you want to put the formula in the cell or do you want the value in the cell, and what cell do you want the value or formula to go?  right now you are only trying to put values in variant variables that as soon as the sub finishes will no longer exist.

Comment: I would like to put the value in cell W23

Comment: For future reference: consider something other than `i` as a `String` variable name. `i` is normally used as a counter variable, e.g. `Dim i As Long`, `For i = 1 to 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `"P2"` and `"Q2"` need to be Ranges, otherwise vba does not know they are references and not strings in their own right.

Also you need to put the range in which you want the values to go on the Left of the `=`

Lastly, get in the habit of declaring you variables and using `Option Explicit` on the top of your modules.  It will help find typos.

```
Sub upstreamA()
    Dim i as String
    i = Right$(ActiveSheet.Range("P2"), 9)
    ActiveSheet.Range("W23").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(i & ": " & ActiveSheet.Range("Q2") & "-A")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To use custom functions, you will need to save the file as .xlsm or one of the other macro enabled formats.

arg1 and arg2 are the values of the cells, and this should work.  Put it wherever you want the value return, and just reference the input cells like you would in any normal function:

=upstreamA(P2, Q2)

```
Function upstreamA(arg1 As String, arg2 As String) As String
    
    Dim buffer As String, i As String
    buffer = ""

    i = Right(arg1, 9)
    buffer = i & ": " & arg2 & "-A"
    
    upstreamA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(buffer)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware.  About to edit it and will include that.

Comment: While you are at editing, it is considered bad form on this site not to declare your variables, even if they are variant.  Too many questions come over this board that could be resolved by use `Option Explicit` and declaring all variables.

Comment: Thanks again.  To tell you the truth, I wasn't 100% sure what he was going to be passing or what he was expecting to get back.  I've updated it with declarations.  Personally I skip them a lot when working just for speed on stuff that isn't going to be passed around or not used much, perhaps not even more than once.  Bad habit, I know.

Comment: I like your option of UDF.  It is more universal.

Comment: And very likely easier to troubleshoot or maintain.  Formulas get tricky fast.